# How to filter the second line in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with 2 lines, and there is an EditText above it, that is used for searching. 
Now I want to filter the second line in this listView. 
How to do that?

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        String[] titleArray,subItemArray;
        data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
            HashMap<String,String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>();

            datum.put("items", list1.get(i));
            datum.put("sumItems", list2.get(i));
            data.add(datum);
        }
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"RouterName", "RouterIP"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
        lst.setAdapter(adapter);
        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                homeActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
```

Comment: What do you mean you have 2 lines. Please explain this point and please add the code as well you tried

Comment: see this image : 
http://www.androidbegin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Filter-ListView-XML-Main.png

Comment: You mean to say you want to filter the list on behalf of second line data if that is true you would have to write custom filter.

Comment: Yes , I added the code that I have tried . I don't know even how to get the value of the second line to work on

Answer (score 0):

Write your custom Filter by implementing your adapter with Filterable interface

```
ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return mFilter;

}



private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {


        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();


        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();


        final List<String> list = originalData;


        int count = list.size();

        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);


        String filterableString ;


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            filterableString = list.get(i);

            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {

                nlist.add(filterableString);

            }

        }


        results.values = nlist;

        results.count = nlist.size();


        return results;

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;

        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}
```